# Fcm Notifications push android/IOS nodejs

Tags: android, ios, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am looking for to send a notification from a Nodejs server, but I am getting some errors that I don't know how solve it. Could someone help me? I found this possible solution on Internet --> [URL](https://hasura.io/blog/quick-howto-fcm-push-notifications-with-nodejs/)

This is my code in nodejs

```
var FCM = require('fcm-push');

function sendNotification (){

var serverKey = 'AAAAJnK3Ing:AP-(more caracters)AwAlBL_CvXIkFM2UufYZHYkvhC7FP3Tu16mlI';
var fcm = new FCM(serverKey);

var message = {
  to: 'd2b2v(more caracters token)DUmAXqU-uHptJJLRPXukl', 
  /*data: {
      your_custom_data_key: 'your_custom_data_value'
  },*/
  notification: {
      title: 'notification',
      body: 'This is a notification from node'
  }
};

//callback style
fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
  if (err) {
      console.log("****************************************************")
      console.log(message)
      console.log("Something has gone wrong!");
  } else {
      console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
  }
});

//promise style
fcm.send(message)
  .then(function(response){
      console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
      console.log("----------------------------------------------------")
      console.log("Something has gone wrong!");
      console.error(err);
  })

}

module.exports = {
  sendNotification
}
```

[I am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P17DO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if your firewall allow to connect on 443 port. It seems like it can't create the connection.

Comment: Yes, it is open and listening